# ffmpeg error when generating screenshots from videos in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I have a function that is supposed to generate a thumbnail from a mp4 file with `fluent-ffmpeg`  in Node, and store it as a jpg file.

In my first function I tried to solve this by creating a stream of the external url:

```
const got = require('got');
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
const ffmpeg_static = require('ffmpeg-static');
const fs = require('fs');

function generateThumbnail() {
   const url = 'https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmUWD7dewFZB9bFamyvR5uEUpX1FEkjuoZYzhUZBm8U4mT/nft.mp4'
   const request = await got.stream(url);

  function asyncThumbnail() {
              return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                ffmpeg(request)
                  .setFfmpegPath(ffmpeg_static)
                  .screenshots({
                    size: '?x512',
                    count: 1,
                    timemarks: ['3'],
                    filename: `filename.jpg`,
                    folder: __dirname + '/../ffmpeg/output',
                  })
                  .on('end', function () {
                    resolve();
                    console.log('Thumbnail created');
                  })
                  .on('error', (err) => {
                    return reject(new Error(err));
                  });
              });
            }
}
```

A thumbnail is generated for a lot of videos I have tested, but not for [this video](https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmUWD7dewFZB9bFamyvR5uEUpX1FEkjuoZYzhUZBm8U4mT/nft.mp4) (the video loads a bit slow because it's hosted on IPFS, but it doesn't have anything to do with my error), which returns the following error:

```
ffmpeg exited with code 1: pipe:0: Invalid data found when processing input
Cannot determine format of input stream 0:0 after EOF
```

After reading that ffmpeg is supposed to work better if I download a video locally before converting it ([link](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg/issues/932#issuecomment-913667263)), I changed my code to do that:

```
const got = require('got');
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
const ffmpeg_static = require('ffmpeg-static');
const fs = require('fs');

function generateThumbnail() {
   const url = 'https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmUWD7dewFZB9bFamyvR5uEUpX1FEkjuoZYzhUZBm8U4mT/nft.mp4'
   const request = await got.stream(url);

   await request.pipe(
              fs.createWriteStream(
                __dirname + `/../ffmpeg/input/fileName.mp4`
              )
            );

  function asyncThumbnail() {
              return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                ffmpeg(__dirname + `/../ffmpeg/input/filename.mp4`)
                  .setFfmpegPath(ffmpeg_static)
                  .screenshots({
                    size: '?x512',
                    count: 1,
                    timemarks: ['3'],
                    filename: `filename.jpg`,
                    folder: __dirname + '/../ffmpeg/output',
                  })
                  .on('end', function () {
                    resolve();
                    console.log('Thumbnail created');
                  })
                  .on('error', (err) => {
                    return reject(new Error(err));
                  });
              });
            }

            await asyncThumbnail();
}
```

This gives me a similar error, but for every video I have tested, without generating a single thumbnail:

```
ffmpeg exited with code 1: C:\path\src/../ffmpeg/input/baroque-fndnft-945.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Running the last function with `fs.createReadStream()` as the `ffmpeg()` input istead gives me this error:

```
ffmpeg exited with code 1: pipe:0: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Comment: Hi there, have you figured out how to solve it?